# Move files from source to destination in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

Further to this question [Unable to print the individually reporting status using Label of JSR223 Sampler in HTML Dashboard Report of JMeter](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/44645/44327).
I am executing a test plan on the server where I have moved files from source to destination folder.

```
   Below is the destination folder hierarchy:
```

1. /sourceFolder/filesThatNeedToBeMoved *to* /destinationFolder/**Input**/
2. /destinationFolder/**Input**/FilesThatAreMovedByMEfromSourceFolder
3. /destinationFolder/**Output**/FilesThatAreMovedAutomaticallyFrom**Input**TO**Output**ByServer

   On the server-side, The destination folder has two subfolders i.e. **INPUT** and **OUTPUT**, when files are moved or copy in the destination folder **INPUT** then those files get automatically deleted by the server and moves to the destination folder **OUTPUT**. I just want to calculate the time of processing of files that are moved from **INPUT** to **OUTPUT** folder automatically by the server.

**How Can I achieve this using Jmeter?** Below I have shared my groovy script where I have written logic for moving the files from source to destination folder INPUT. And unable to calculate the time between INPUT To OUTPUT folder.

**Can we run the script until the specific files get deleted from the INPUT folder or not?**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer
log.info("############################################################# START #############################################################");

def SOURCE = vars.get('source');
log.info("SOURCE IS : " + SOURCE);
def DESTINATION = vars.get('destination');
def DATA = vars.get('data');
def SMS = vars.get('sms');
def VOICE = vars.get('voice');

def baseDestinationFolder = new String(DESTINATION);

log.info(baseDestinationFolder); 
def dataDestFolder = baseDestinationFolder + DATA;
def SMSDestFolder = baseDestinationFolder + SMS;
def VoiceDestFolder = baseDestinationFolder + VOICE;
log.info("dataDestFolder : " + dataDestFolder);
log.info("SMSDestFolder : "+SMSDestFolder);
log.info("VoiceDestFolder : " + VoiceDestFolder);

File sourceFolder = new File(SOURCE); 
log.info("******* SOURCE FOLDER IS ******** : " + sourceFolder);
File[] datafiles = sourceFolder.listFiles();     


for (File inputFile : datafiles){
        def fileName = "" + inputFile.getName();
        log.info("fileName : " + fileName);
        def finalPath;
        if(fileName.contains("data")){
            SampleResult.setSampleLabel("Source: " + SOURCE + "::" + "Destination: " +  DESTINATION + DATA);
            log.info( "The Sample Label is : " + SampleResult.getSampleLabel() );
            finalPath = dataDestFolder + fileName;
        }else if(fileName.contains("voice")){
            SampleResult.setSampleLabel("Source: " + SOURCE + "::" + "Destination: " +  DESTINATION + VOICE);
            log.info( "The Sample Label is : " + SampleResult.getSampleLabel() );
            finalPath = VoiceDestFolder + fileName;
        }else if(fileName.contains("sms")){
            SampleResult.setSampleLabel("Source: " + SOURCE + "::" + "Destination: " +  DESTINATION + SMS);
            log.info( "The Sample Label is : " + SampleResult.getSampleLabel() );
            finalPath = SMSDestFolder + fileName;
        }

        log.info("finalPath is : " + finalPath);
        def newFile = new File(finalPath);
        newFile << inputFile.text
    }


log.info("############################################################# END #############################################################");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check **only** the file processing time **by your server** and report it, you can measure this time using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) like:

```
def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
while (!new File('/destinationFolder/Output/').list().toList().containsAll('file1', 'file2', 'file3')) {
    sleep(100)
}
def end = System.currentTimeMillis()
prev.time = (end - start)
```

it will wait until all files you expect to be under `/destinationFolder/Output/` will appear there and then update the parent [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) execution time with the server processing time

More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: If I move 100 files, then I have to send 100 files like this or is there any way to send simply a list object in `.containsAll()`.method. And, Can I use direct JSR223 sampler variables in JSR223 post processor?

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I just want the processing time by my server. I don't want to add the processing time to the `prev.time`. So how can we remove the previous time response and add only the file processing time to it?